# Angular 5: Route :id parameter as a string not work when page reload on URL

Tags: angular, angular5, azure-web-app-service, router

I would appreciate if anyone can help me.

Consider below notes:

- We have hosted a site on Azure app service
- route as **path: 'security-roles/edit/:id'**

Here I wanted to pass a string as id parameter rather than a number as below

Worked URL: https://xxxx.azurewebsites.net/security-roles/edit/10

Ref.URL (Not work): https://xxxx.azurewebsites.net/security-roles/edit/c3xSHfcJFWiDpUTKPAyvlw%253d%253d

First time work but not work when page reload.

On page reload give an error as below,

**"The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable."**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks like you're missing a slash after the `edit` portion of your route.

Comment: You are using :id which will work as optional route parameter and on reload it will reset.

Comment: @Edric, Thanks for your input. I have had added a slash after the edit portion in route. I was my typing mistake.